# Launch second activity

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login

I am dealing with facebook sdk in my android application. What I am doing here, when user presses icon of application, user will first see the button for Login Via Facebook in my application. When user clikcs on this Login button, user will be directed to facebook login screen, where user has to input username and password. After successful login, user will be directed to second activity. Now, what I want here is, after using application when user presses home button or back button, and again presses icon of application, then user should not be directed to first activity which has Login button, instead user should be directed to second activity of app, as session is opened. This case should remain untill user Logouts. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

With adding splashActivity to your application you can get solution.....splashActivity must be launcher activity and in OnCreate method of splashActivity you can check If Facebook Session Valid then redirect to second activity otherwise call first activity....

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use preference for what you want exactly. Use one flag as **'Y'** or **'N'**. when user logged in successfully in your application put flag as **'Y'** and don't change it until logout. when user click on logout button put value of flag as **'N'**

- And finally you have to check your preference's value at your
  starting activity.

**Edit:** As per your requirement

```
Context activityContext; 
SessionManager objSessionManager;
    public class MainActivity extends Activity 
    {
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.login_page);
            activityContext = MainActivity.this;

            objSessionManager = new SessionManager(activityContext); // My preference

            if(objSessionManager.isLoggedIn()) // checking for flag
            {
                Intent i = new Intent(activityContext ,Your_Second_Activity.class);
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
                    else
                    {
                           // put your code here of First Activity that is Facebook login.
                    }
        }
  }
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: how can check it? Means I have to write this code on Restart method?

Comment: you should check on your first activity. as per your flag pass the intent.

Comment: But I don't want first activity every time..If session is opened and user presses app icon, then should be directed to second activity

Comment: just put these conditions on your mainactivity in oncreate method just below setcontentview();. i have done it with and it works for me.

Comment: can u provide some examples related to this?

Comment: @David...what are the types of objSessionManager and activityContext here...?

Comment: Context activityContext;
 and SessionManager objSessionManager; @AnilBhatiya

Answer (score 0):

I am not that familiar with Facebook SDK, but this is a common way to solve this kind of problem:

1. When the user logs in, save his session id or whatever Facebook calls you back.
2. Save that to a file
3. When your app is restarted, take a look at that file and try to issue a simple Facebook API call with that session id. If successful, start a new `Intent` to your second activity.
4. If not, proceed with first activity.

**Note:** Take care to encrypt the file.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, found the solution...Working...

```
 @Override
        protected void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            Session session = Session.getActiveSession();

            if (session != null && session.isOpened())
            {
                Intent in = new Intent(getBaseContext(), NextActivity.class);
                startActivity(in);

            } 
            else 
            {

            }
        }
```